# How to use symfony/messenger In console commands symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony

to work with the queue manager I use the standard package in Symfony 5

> "symfony/messenger": "5.2.*"

Usually when I use it in my controller I do something like this:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="home")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
      $this->dispatchMessage($message); // Sending a message to the queue manager
```

This works fine when my controller inherits AbstractController
But I need to trigger the dispatchMessage event from the console command

```
class NotificationCommand extends Command
{
    private $entity_manager;
    private $twig;
    private $params;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entity_manager,Environment $twig,ContainerBagInterface $params,string $name = null)
    {
        $this->entity_manager = $entity_manager;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->params = $params;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
     // Here you need to do something like $this->dispatchMessage($message);
```

But the trouble is that *Command* does not inherit  *AbstractController*
Accordingly, I cannot address through *$this* to this case
Usually I solved this problem by passing to *__construct* various interfaces (you can see an example of how I do this for entity manager, twig and params )

**But what should I convey for "messenger" ?**

Or how to use it differently from the console command?

Comment: Check `dispatchMessage`, maybe you can inject your messenger to console command?

Comment: Use [dependency injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#dispatching-the-message) to inject the `Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface $bus` service into the service constructor, Then call `$bus->dispatch($message);` Post your `config/services.yaml` for the `NotificationCommand` if youre having issues with DI.

Comment: Why not check whatever `$this->dispatchMessage` does, and also do that in your own code?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help, sorry for the long answer, I was busy, but the advice from the second comment worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `MessageBusInterface` into your console command like this

```
//...
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class NotificationCommand extends Command
{
    //...
    private $bus;

    public function __construct(/*...,*/ MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        //...
        $this->bus = $bus;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        //...
        $this->bus->dispatch(new YourMessageToDispatch());
    }
```